# mapping a simple calculation over rows and lists using dplyr

Tags: r

I have some data which looks similar to the following:

```
$`2013 Jul`
# A tibble: 3 x 12
      AAPL     AMD      ADI    ABBV        A      APD       AA       CF     NVDA      HOG      WMT     AMZN
     <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 -0.00252 0.00385 0.000314 0.00148 0.000231 0.000655 -0.00107 -0.00137 0.000886 0.000806 0.000689 0.000615
2  1       5       2        5       2        3         1        1       4        4        3        3       
3  0.2     0.2     0        0.2     0        0         0.2      0.2     0        0        0        0
```

What I am trying to do is when row 2 == 1, multiply row 3 by -1. Such that the expected output would be:

```
$`2013 Jul`
# A tibble: 3 x 12
      AAPL     AMD      ADI    ABBV        A      APD       AA       CF     NVDA      HOG      WMT     AMZN
     <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 -0.00252 0.00385 0.000314 0.00148 0.000231 0.000655 -0.00107 -0.00137 0.000886 0.000806 0.000689 0.000615
2  1       5       2        5       2        3         1        1       4        4        3        3       
3 -0.2     0.2     0        0.2     0        0        -0.2     -0.2     0        0        0        0
```

I am trying to do this using the `map` functions and `tidyr`.

Data:

```
lst1 <- list(`2013 Jul` = structure(list(AAPL = c(-0.00252413896048252, 
1, 0.2), AMD = c(0.00385385230384388, 5, 0.2), ADI = c(0.000313658814841043, 
2, 0), ABBV = c(0.00148473194650269, 5, 0.2), A = c(0.000231372267065186, 
2, 0), APD = c(0.000654593370621786, 3, 0), AA = c(-0.00106999405402468, 
1, 0.2), CF = c(-0.00136811540143579, 1, 0.2), NVDA = c(0.000886435916090005, 
4, 0), HOG = c(0.000806051331850114, 4, 0), WMT = c(0.000689490484865284, 
3, 0), AMZN = c(0.000614708184565435, 3, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2013 Aug` = structure(list(
    AAPL = c(0.0000471064768722691, 1, 0.2), AMD = c(0.00297250845145986, 
    5, 0.2), ADI = c(0.00110927645875706, 3, 0), ABBV = c(0.00186505842086247, 
    4, 0), A = c(0.0000542259939665846, 2, 0), APD = c(0.00187188084293685, 
    5, 0.2), AA = c(-0.000794925865044543, 1, 0.2), CF = c(-0.00109320436559941, 
    1, 0.2), NVDA = c(0.00139874295083158, 4, 0), HOG = c(0.000699507074667968, 
    2, 0), WMT = c(0.000964557826996342, 3, 0), AMZN = c(0.00100980845937234, 
    3, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")), `2013 Sep` = structure(list(AAPL = c(0.000874550640770086, 
3, 0), AMD = c(0.00212896308150426, 5, 0.2), ADI = c(0.000297401899798995, 
1, 0.2), ABBV = c(0.00126327568847214, 4, 0), A = c(0.00097767693668047, 
3, 0), APD = c(0.00144402630305102, 5, 0.2), AA = c(-0.000734440361937234, 
1, 0.2), CF = c(-0.000254998800234454, 1, 0.2), NVDA = c(0.00127259056829905, 
4, 0), HOG = c(0.00105093597431519, 3, 0), WMT = c(0.00038339075327491, 
2, 0), AMZN = c(0.000479002073488143, 2, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2013 Oct` = structure(list(
    AAPL = c(0.000682565466572836, 2, 0), AMD = c(0.00313699867162714, 
    5, 0.2), ADI = c(0.000209923665516306, 1, 0.2), ABBV = c(0.000865756791407934, 
    2, 0), A = c(0.00161631482825611, 4, 0), APD = c(0.00169177940768777, 
    5, 0.2), AA = c(-0.000319519044240903, 1, 0.2), CF = c(0.00096163857613333, 
    3, 0), NVDA = c(0.00158604241362254, 4, 0), HOG = c(0.00151424115101764, 
    3, 0), WMT = c(0.00000265229900199134, 1, 0.2), AMZN = c(0.00124777917896926, 
    3, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")), `2013 Nov` = structure(list(AAPL = c(0.00138847413611967, 
4, 0), AMD = c(0.00131189086851618, 3, 0), ADI = c(0.000998905149605624, 
2, 0), ABBV = c(0.00053428429850944, 1, 0.2), A = c(0.0016278252466143, 
4, 0), APD = c(0.00186840190432607, 5, 0.2), AA = c(0.000727945791304539, 
1, 0.2), CF = c(0.00128641077503917, 3, 0), NVDA = c(0.000839077672381489, 
2, 0), HOG = c(0.00128443125529569, 3, 0), WMT = c(-0.00000406995915300601, 
1, 0.2), AMZN = c(0.00279573900270221, 5, 0.2)), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `2013 Dec` = structure(list(
    AAPL = c(0.00176889092052374, 5, 0.2), AMD = c(-0.000742603775364103, 
    1, 0.2), ADI = c(0.00044132637464973, 1, 0.2), ABBV = c(0.00113925715965696, 
    3, 0), A = c(0.00135042334177499, 4, 0), APD = c(0.0012375761024876, 
    3, 0), AA = c(0.00102055404174894, 2, 0), CF = c(0.00128611035428346, 
    3, 0), NVDA = c(0.000674203833347995, 2, 0), HOG = c(0.00164877495332821, 
    4, 0), WMT = c(0.000671450466059644, 1, 0.2), AMZN = c(0.00299158521138261, 
    5, 0.2)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")))
```

Comment: Apologies. The values in row 2 can take `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` so when the value in this row is `1` then I want to modify row 3 by multiplying it by `-1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
map(lst1, ~ .x %>%
     mutate_all(~ if_else(row_number() == 3 & lag(.) == 1, . * -1, .)))

$`2013 Jul`
# A tibble: 3 x 12
      AAPL     AMD     ADI    ABBV       A     APD       AA       CF    NVDA     HOG
     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 -0.00252 0.00385 3.14e-4 0.00148 2.31e-4 6.55e-4 -0.00107 -0.00137 8.86e-4 8.06e-4
2  1       5       2.00e+0 5       2.00e+0 3.00e+0  1        1       4.00e+0 4.00e+0
3 -0.2     0.2     0.      0.2     0.      0.      -0.2     -0.2     0.      0.     
# … with 2 more variables: WMT <dbl>, AMZN <dbl>
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're not restricted to using those specific packages, a base R solution could be to use

```
> lapply(lst1, function(df) do.call(cbind, lapply(df, function(col) {
    col[3] <- ifelse(col[2]==1, -col[3], col[3])
    return (col)
})))
# 
# $`2013 Jul`
#              AAPL         AMD           ADI         ABBV           A
# [1,] 0.0006825655 0.003136999  0.0002099237 0.0008657568 0.001616315
# [2,] 2.0000000000 5.000000000  1.0000000000 2.0000000000 4.000000000
# [3,] 0.0000000000 0.200000000 -0.2000000000 0.0000000000 0.000000000
#              APD           AA           CF        NVDA         HOG
# [1,] 0.001691779 -0.000319519 0.0009616386 0.001586042 0.001514241
# [2,] 5.000000000  1.000000000 3.0000000000 4.000000000 3.000000000
# [3,] 0.200000000 -0.200000000 0.0000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000
#                WMT        AMZN
# [1,]  2.652299e-06 0.001247779
# [2,]  1.000000e+00 3.000000000
# [3,] -2.000000e-01 0.000000000
# ...
```

which loops over all data frames of in lst1, subsequently loops over all columns in each data frame and changes the third row according to the second row value.

Answer (score 3):

An option with `case_when` and `map`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map(lst1, ~ .x %>%  
           mutate_all(~
         case_when(row_number() == 3 & lag(.)== 1 ~ -1 * ., TRUE ~ .)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `[<-.data.frame` within `map` to replace the elements in row 3 where row 2 is 1 with their negative.

```
lst1 %>% 
  map(~ {i <- c(.x[2,] == 1); .x[3, i] <- -.x[3, i]; .x})
```